# SESSION Check - in user pages

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

So, there are many posts on sessions, however, none of them are quite clear enough in redirecting users to another page if the user is logged out and is trying to access members only pages. I am looking for sessions that once logged out, you can't go back. Understandably, that will require java script, instead, I am looking to disable copying and pasting web addresses straight into the browser, if they do, and they are not logged in, they should be redirected to the login page. Here are the codes...

**All member pages start with this:

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){
    session_start();        
}else{
    header("Location:login.php");
}

include("connection.php");
```

**Connection page just connects to database, simple names and password or die.

**su.php. This page is what starts the session upon logging in or signing up. Logging our actually logs them out, again the problem is anyone can just go type in the address of profile.php and pull it up.

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION ) ){
    session_start();
}

    if($_GET["logout"]==1 AND $_SESSION['id']) { session_destroy();

            header("Location:logout.php");          
    }

include("connection.php");

if ($_POST['submit']=="Sign Up") {

    if (!$_POST['email']) $error.="<br />Please enter your email";
        else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address";

    if (!$_POST['password']) $error.="<br />Please enter your password";
        else {

        if (strlen($_POST['password'])<8) $error.="<br />Please enter a password with at least 8 characters";
        if (!preg_match('`[A-Z]`', $_POST['password'])) $error.="<br />Please enter at least 1 capital letter";

        }

     if ($error) $error = "There were error(s) in your signup details:".$error;
     else {


        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";

        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

        $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($results) $error = "That email address is already registered";

        else {

            $query="INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."')";

            mysqli_query($link, $query);

            $message = "You've been signed up!";

            $_SESSION['id']=mysqli_insert_id($link);              

            header("Location:registration.php");

        }

    }

}

 if ($_POST['submit']=="Log In") {

    $query="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['loginemail'])."' AND password='".md5(md5($_POST['loginemail']).$_POST['loginpassword'])."' LIMIT 1";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if ($row) {

        $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];

            header("Location:dashboard.php");

        } else {

         $loginerror = "We could not find a user with that email and password. Please try again.";

        }

    }
```

Comment: Include a check for session at the beginning of each page and redirect accordingly. We typically create a file that is included at the top of each page that tests for certain session variables. If those are not there we redirect.

Comment: won't help to do the check in PHP if the user can simply go back and access any cached pages in their browser. if you want to enforce a "logged out" state, you'd have to make the html of all your pages uncacheable, forcing the user's browser to fetch a fresh copy every time the page is loaded.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string concatenation to accomplish this because you will make a mistake and create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: So how would the code look for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
?>
```

member page content

```
<?php
}
else
{
 header("Location:login.php");
}
?>
```

**Explanation:**
Initially you should start the session and then you should check whether the session variable you passed is there for that member page.

Or you can simply have

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
 header("Location:login.php");
}
?>
```

on the top of the page

Comment: You should explain why that would help.

Comment: thanks for asking @Felix but Anthony just asked only for the code in his final comment.

Comment: Stack overflow is a site for questions and answers, a *public* site. Your answer is not only directed to the Original Poster, but towards **the internet population too**. As such, never assume an answer of yours do not need explanations because the op understands. I will flag answers lacking context, and those answers are not highly valued here. Your answer as it is now, even though lacking some formatting, is probably more useful than the few lines originally present.